# D3: how to make this variable universal?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to reproduce Mike Bostock's Object Constancy example. 
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/

I read in my data, clean it, nest it, then call redraw()

When I call redraw(), I get error "Can't find variable nested_data"
This error makes sense to me.  It seems nested_data is indeed a local variable.

OTOH, my code throws the error on line 103. I would have expected it at 98.

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/greencracker/d767c9065c2a645868c4

The question is, how come Bostock's example works?  Seems like it shouldn't.

How can I fix mine:

[image]

[image]

For reference, Bostock's. Annotations by me. 
[image]

Comment: If you look at your code and his, your variable is declared with `var` in the function while his has already been declared elsewhere and he is simply being initialized. To make it global just put `var nested_data;` outside of all your function bodies.

Comment: You declare the variable in a function, which means it's local to only that function. You *could* make it a global, although whether or not that's a good (enough) idea is debatable.

Comment: @DaveNewton He actually already has a whole bunch of globals if you look at the gist he linked https://gist.github.com/greencracker/d767c9065c2a645868c4

Comment: @AR7 I didn't, because questions should be self-contained.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: Thanks @AR7; put it as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable in a function it only exists locally inside of that function. To fix this you need to declare the variable `nested_data` outside of the scope of the function to give it a global scope.

So you would put `var nested_data;` where you put all your other global declarations in your [gist](https://gist.github.com/greencracker/d767c9065c2a645868c4).

This way you can initialize your variable inside your function body just using

```
nested_data = d3.nest()....other stuff
```

and still have access to your variable inside another function.